# JupyterHub with Public Key authentication

Tags: python, authentication, public-key, jupyterhub

I am currently install Jupyterhub using sudo spawner. However, it gets into error on PAM authentication because we are using public key authentication.

How can we install JupyterHub with Public Key authentication?

Comment: You would probably need to use [SSL Client Certification Authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/44007)